# PostgreSQL database with row versioning

Tags: sql, postgresql

Just wanted to start out by saying much love to the StackOverflow community :)

So I have a Postgres database table, but let's reduce to the significant columns:

```
id (string/int), when (timestamp/time/date), canonical (boolean)
```

*Canonical* in this case means "accepted part of the version history".

Let's say our table looks like this:

```
2, 2003-01-08, true
2, 2002-01-08, false
1, 2001-01-08, false
3, 2000-01-08, false
2, 2000-01-08, true
1, 2000-01-08, true
1, 1999-01-08, true
```

I want a query that will find the **latest canonical version for each ID**. The result should look like:

```
2, 2003-01-08, true
1, 2000-01-08, true
```

So two questions I guess:

1. How would you write a query for this?
2. Can it be indexed?

A larger, more meta-question, is if there is a better way to handle storing this sort of information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select distinct on (id) *
from t
where canonical
order by id, "when" desc
```

The best index for this query would be the partial index

```
create index index_name on t (id, "when" desc) where canonical;
```

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createindex.html

Comment: Wow that was so quick! Thank you so much :)

Comment: We tested both, and while the second one does fewer operations, this one can grab other columns in the table without a problem :) Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

```
select id, max("when")
from t
where canonical
group by id;
```

*Maybe* [faster](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/aadf1/3) in some cases than the `distinct on` variant, and you don't need to sort your results by `id`.

Comment: This is great too :) I'll try both, see how it goes. Thanks!

Comment: That sqlfiddle tool is awesome, btw :)